# What is the inverse operation of indexing in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have two arrays `a` and `b` of length `n` and `m` respectively, where `n > m`, `a` has values in 1,...,m and `b` is a permutation of 1,...,m:

```
# n > m
n = 20000
m = 10000

a = np.random.randint(1, m + 1, size=n)
b = np.random.permutation(m) + 1
```

How can I find an array `c` of length `n` with values in 1,...,m such that the following holds?

```
assert(b[c-1]==a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```py
_, c = np.nonzero(b == a[:, None])
assert np.allclose(b[c], a)
```

Just note that it asserts `b[c]` to `a` instead of `b[c-1]`.

**Working**:

The line `b == a[:, None]` returns a boolean array of shape *n x m*, where each row compares the row index-th element of `a` with all elements of `b`. That is why you have `m` boolean elements in a row with `True` in the corresponding column index `col` where that element from `a` equals to `b[col]`. This uses [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for elementwise comparison.

This is a small illustration:

```py
>>> m = 5
>>> n = 10
>>> a = np.random.randint(1, m+1, size=n)
>>> b = np.random.permutation(m) + 1
>>> a
array([5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2])
>>> b
array([3, 5, 1, 2, 4])
>>> b == a[:, None]
array([[False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]])
```

On applying [`np.nonzero()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), on this *2D* boolean array, you get 2 *1D* arrays of row and column indices of where the passed array has `True` elements i.e., each `(i[k], j[k])` position of the boolean array has `True`. Here I have shown the row and column index arrays as `i` and `j`.

```
>>> i, j = np.nonzero(b == a[:, None])
>>> i
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> j
array([1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3])
```

In a way the columns `j` gives how the array `a` can be obtained by indexing `b` with `j`.

```
>>> b[j]
array([5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2])
>>> a
array([5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2])
```

Essentially you have elements in `a` coming from the *set* `b`. The idea above is just to compare where each element in `a` appears in `b` and then get the corresponding index.

Comment: @user175348: Added the explanation with an example. Feel free to ask for further clarifications.